# Proving $\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{4}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{99}+\sqrt{100}}>\frac{9}{2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> Prove that
> $$\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{4}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{99}+\sqrt{100}}>\frac{9}{2}$$

How do I prove this without actually performing the calculation?
I thought about rationalizing the terms but with the sum I got , I still can't go any further.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hint: Add the missing series: i.e. $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2+\sqrt 3}+\frac{1}{\sqrt 4+\sqrt 5}+...+\frac{1}{\sqrt 98+\sqrt 99}$. Find the sum of the combined series. Also compare the values of the added series and the original series.

Comment: The sum of the original series is more than the sum of the added series, right? And their combined sum is 9. Ah! Thank you so much, I got it!

Comment: But why is the sum of the added series less than that of the original series?

Comment: You can compare the 2 series term by term.

Comment: It is a very tricky inequality!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $$S=\frac{1}{\sqrt 1+\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{4}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{99}+\sqrt{100}}$$

Rationalising the terms gives

$$S=\sqrt 2-\sqrt 1+\sqrt 4-\sqrt 3+\cdots+\sqrt{100}-\sqrt{99}$$

Now let $$\begin{align}T &= \frac{1}{\sqrt 2+\sqrt{3}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{4}+
\sqrt{5}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{98}+\sqrt{99}}\\
\\
&=\sqrt 3-\sqrt 2+\sqrt 5-\sqrt 4+\cdots+\sqrt{99}-\sqrt{98}\end{align}$$

Then $S+T=\sqrt{100}-\sqrt{1}=9$. But $S>T$, so $S>\frac92$.

---

Credit for this idea goes to user Maverick, who sketched it out in [this almost-duplicate question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3422567/1508). I would have just linked to it, but it would have needed extensive editing to correct the mistakes.

Comment: But why is S>T?

Comment: Because $\frac{1}{\sqrt 1+\sqrt 2}>\frac{1}{\sqrt 2+\sqrt 3},\frac{1}{\sqrt 3+\sqrt 4}>\frac{1}{\sqrt 4+\sqrt 5},\ldots,\frac{1}{\sqrt{97}+\sqrt{98}}>\frac{1}{\sqrt{98}+\sqrt{99}}$.

Answer (score 3):

So we want to estimate $s_{50}$ where

$$s_n = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k$$

and $a_k$ satisfies

$$\begin{align}
a_k &= \frac1{\sqrt{2k-1}+\sqrt{2k}} \\
&> \frac1{\sqrt{2k-1}+\sqrt{2k+1}} \\
&= \frac{\sqrt{2k+1}-\sqrt{2k-1}}{(\sqrt{2k+1}+\sqrt{2k-1})(\sqrt{2k+1}-\sqrt{2k-1})} \\
&= \frac12(\sqrt{2k+1}-\sqrt{2k-1}) \\
\end{align}$$

Where the denominator of the last line uses $(a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2$. This gives an estimate for $s_{50}$ that's a telescopting sum:

$$\begin{align}
s_{50} = \sum_{k=1}^{50}a_k 
&> \frac12\sum_{k=1}^{50}(\sqrt{2k+1}-\sqrt{2k-1}) \\
&= \frac12(\sqrt{101}-\sqrt{1}) \\
&> \frac12(\sqrt{100}-\sqrt{1}) 
= 9/2
\end{align}$$

Comment: Excellent and very clear proof!!